# Degree of horror for several verbs

Tags: meaning, difference, ambiguity

Could someone please sort the level of each of these verbs in the degree of horror?

appal, dismay, horrify, shock, startle

Answer (score 1):

From least to worst, I would say:

### 1. startle

This implies a small, sudden, shock - something which is quickly dismissed because there was no actual peril.

### 2. dismay

I was in two minds whether to put this first or second. It means to be concerned about something, so as this implies a genuine cause for that feeling I feel it is "worse" than simply being startled. However, in common usage "dismay" does not really carry the idea of a sudden or unexpected event (even though dictionary definitions say so) and many speakers use it to describe feelings about an ongoing or prolonged issue.

### 3. shock

A shock can also turn out to be something benign - just something sudden that takes you by surprise. When used for something *ongoing* (eg. *This situation is shocking!*) this plays down the surprise element somewhat. Still, this is worse than a "startle".

### 4. horrify

The dictionary says this is something that "fills you with horror". [Overuse of words](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appalling%2C%20horrifying%2C%20appall%2C%20appal%2C%20horrify&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cappalling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chorrifying%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cappall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cappal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chorrify%3B%2Cc0) does subtract from their impact somewhat, and while the term "horrify" is more widely used than "appal", the word "appalling" is used more than "horrifying". For this reason I was also in two minds about these final two rankings.

### 5. appal

As mentioned above, "appalling" is widely used, and while the dictionary defines it as "*greatly horrified*" it has to rank above "horrify" which would rank it as worse, I am not completely sure that it ought to be. "Appalling", to me, is more about feeling *disgusted* than *scared*. People say that food or service is "appalling", whereas the word "horror" is far more synonymous with fear. So, I've ranked it here as the dictionary says I should, but I would consider taking it off this list alltogether (along with "dismay") if you are strictly talking about levels of fear.

Answer (score 0):

startle...shock...dismay...appall...horrify

Comment: And which one is more stronger?

Comment: What do you think, based on your reading of the dictionary definitions?

Comment: horrify looks stronger. but appall does not look strong (according to google images).

Comment: Google Images is not a reliable indicator.

Comment: Also, people can be exaggerating when they use these words. For example, I could say I was *appalled* that you tried to get a sense of the meaning of these words by consulting Google Images. Or they could say that they were *horrified* when the cake they were baking came out of the oven a little overbaked.